# One sided limit of composite function

Tags: limits

When finding a simple one sided limit of a non-continuous function, I can easily see what the limit is.  When the function becomes a composite function, is each portion of the composite limit taken from one side?

**Generalized example:**

$f(x) =$ \begin{cases} -2, & \mbox{if } -\infty < x < -2 \\ 0, & \mbox{if } -2 \le x < 0 \\ 2, & \mbox{if } 0 \le x < 2 \\ -2, & \mbox{if } 2\le x < \infty \end{cases}

Take $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}} f(f(x))$

**My attempt:**

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = 2$

then I become stuck here

$\lim\limits_{x \to 2^{+}} f(x) = -2$

but

$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} f(x) = DNE$

This leads to the original question.  When the function is used twice, is the limit evaluated from one side for each portion (e.g. $f(0^{+})$ and $f(2^{+})$?  OR Is the the limit evaluated from the right side for $f(0^{+})$ and both sides at $f(2)$?

Comment: "Let f(x) = -2 from (-inf, -2), x = 0 from [-2,0), x = 2 from [0,2) and x -2 from [2, inf)."

Comment: I attempted to clarify the question.  I think your answer still stands, but I wanted to give you the chance to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

"Let f(x) = -2 from (-inf, -2), x = 0 from [-2,0), x = 2 from [0,2) and x -2 from [2, inf)." You mean "Let f(x) = -2 from (-inf, -2), f(x) = 0 from [-2,0), f(x) = 2 from [0,2) and f(x)=  -2 from [2, inf).

I see no "nesting" here.  This is a piece-wise function. Taking the limit for x going to 2 from above we are only interested in values of x which are larger than 2 and close to 2.  That is we are only interested in "f(x)= -2 from [2, inf)".  $\lim_{x\to 2^+} f(x)= -2$.

Comment: You are correct on the notation, the x’s I wrote should be f(x). However, that still leaves the question of f(f(x)). I get that it’s a piecewise and the limit DNE for my example. The issue I have is one sided where the limit exists. After I evaluate the first stage, do I also one-side the second step? That’s the nested part.